# How to generate a task number (string) that contains multiple decimals, and update all following task numbers?

Tags: javascript, string, blazor, decimal, webassembly

I have a numbering system that uses multiple decimals to denote steps and sub-steps of a task. For instance, "1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.2.1". These tasks are displayed sequentially in the browser using a js framework that mimics excel. The user uses keyboard shortcuts and/or a dialog box to move a selected step/sub-step up or down a level. So if a user moved "1.1" up a level the new task number would be "2". A sub-step can exist without a preceding sub-step. For instance, "1" can be followed by "1.1.1".

**What is the best way to generate the new task number AND update all following task numbers?** See the following image for desired result.

[image: Desired Result]

Below is my current solution.

Called when a user activates the function to move a task number down one level.

```
 for (var i = activeSheet.getActiveRowIndex(); i < (activeSheet.getActiveRowIndex() + 1); i++) {
                    var taskNumberCellValue = activeSheet.getCell(i, 0).value();
                    var taskLevel = (taskNumberCellValue.match(/\./g) || []).length + 1;
                    var targetLevel = taskLevel + 1;
                    activeSheet.getCell(i, 0).value(this.generateWorkingElementNumber(i, targetLevel, activeSheet));
}
this.updateWorkElementNumbering(activeSheet, namedRange, activeSheet.getActiveRowIndex());
```

Called when a user activates the function to move a task number up one level.

```
 for (var i = activeSheet.getActiveRowIndex(); i < (activeSheet.getActiveRowIndex() + 1); i++) {
                    var taskNumberCellValue = activeSheet.getCell(i, 0).value();
                    var taskLevel = (taskNumberCellValue.match(/\./g) || []).length + 1;

                    var targetLevel = taskLevel - 1;
                    activeSheet.getCell(i, 0).value(this.generateWorkingElementNumber(i, targetLevel, activeSheet));
                }

                // TODO: PUT THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION CALL INTO A LOOP TO ACCOUNT FOR multiple selected rows
                this.updateWorkElementNumbering(activeSheet, namedRange, activeSheet.getActiveRowIndex());
```

The following two functions are called when a user wants to move a task number up or down.
This function generates the task number for the selected row. This is the row the user selected when they triggered the command to move the task number up or down one level.

```
 generateWorkingElementNumber: function (rowNumber, targetLevel, activeSheet) {
        var previousTaskNumberCellValue = activeSheet.getCell(rowNumber - 1, 0).value();
        var previousTaskLevel = (previousTaskNumberCellValue.match(/\./g) || []).length + 1;
        var splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue = previousTaskNumberCellValue.split(".");

        var selectedTaskNumber = activeSheet.getCell(rowNumber, 0).value();
        var selectedTaskNumberLevel = (selectedTaskNumber.match(/\./g) || []).length + 1;
        var splitSelectedTaskNumber = selectedTaskNumber.split(".");

        var taskNumToReturn = splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0];
        
        if (targetLevel > previousTaskLevel) {
            for (var i = 2; i <= previousTaskLevel; i++) {
                taskNumToReturn = taskNumToReturn + "." + splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[i - 1];
            }

            for (var i = (previousTaskLevel + 1); i <= targetLevel; i++) {
                taskNumToReturn = taskNumToReturn + "." + "1";
            }
        }
        else {
            if (targetLevel == 1) {
                taskNumToReturn = (parseInt(splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0]) + 1).toString();
                return taskNumToReturn;
            }
            else {
                taskNumToReturn = splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0];
            }

            for (var i = 2; i < (targetLevel); i++) {
                taskNumToReturn = taskNumToReturn + "." + splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[i - 1];
            }
            taskNumToReturn = taskNumToReturn + "." + (parseInt(splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[targetLevel - 1]) + 1).toString();
        }
        return taskNumToReturn
    }
```

Function updates all task numbers that follow the task number of the selected row.

Parameter context: "activeSheet" is a js instance of the current sheet. Exposes functions provided by the js framework I am using. "namedRange" allows me to know what row contains the last task number. "rowNumber" is the row number of the currently selected row.

```
updateTaskNumbering: function (activeSheet, namedRange, rowNumber) {
        var previousTaskNumberCellValue = activeSheet.getCell((rowNumber - 1), 0).value();
        var previousTaskLevel = (previousTaskNumberCellValue .match(/\./g) || []).length + 1;
        var splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue = previousTaskNumberCellValue.split(".");

        var taskNumToReturn = splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0];
        for (var i = rowNumber; i < (namedRange.Lf.endRow + 1); i++) {
            var selectedTaskNumber = activeSheet.getCell(i, 0).value();
            var selectedTaskNumberLevel = (selectedTaskNumber.match(/\./g) || []).length + 1;
            var targetLevel = selectedTaskNumberLevel;

            if (targetLevel > previousTaskLevel) {
                taskNumToReturn = splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0];
                for (var j = 2; j <= previousTaskLevel; j++) {
                    taskNumToReturn = taskNumToReturn + "." + splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[j-1];
                }

                for (var k = (previousTaskLevel+ 1); k <= targetLevel; k++) {
                    splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[k-1] = 1;
                    taskNumToReturn = taskNumToReturn + "." + "1";
                }
            }
            else {
                if (targetLevel == 1) {
                    splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0] = (parseInt(splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0]) + 1).toString();
                    taskNumToReturn = splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0];
                }
                else {
                    taskNumToReturn = splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[0];
                    for (var l = 2; l <= (targetLevel - 1); l++) {
                        taskNumToReturn = taskNumToReturn + "." + splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[l];
                    }
                    splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[targetLevel - 1] = (parseInt(splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[targetLevel - 1]) + 1).toString();
                    taskNumToReturn = taskNumToReturn + "." + splitPreviousTaskNumberCellValue[targetLevel - 1];
                }
            }
            activeSheet.getCell(i, 0).value(taskNumToReturn);
            previousTaskLevel = targetLevel;
        }
    },
```

The above functions are working well. I will provide feedback or update the code as I find any bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is not a complete solution, but you can solve this relatively simply by having each task delegate to the parent for most of the label:

ASSUMPTION: Only top level tasks have real level numbers - all children are derived

```js
class Task {
  parentTask = null
  children = []
  level = 0

  constructor(parentTask, level) {
    if (parentTask) {
      parentTask.adopt(this)
    }
    this.level = parentTask? 0 : (level || 1)
    this.children = []
  }

  toString() {
    if (this.parentTask)
      return this.parentTask.toString() + "." + this.parentTask.children.indexOf(this)
    return this.level
  }

  adopt(child) {
      child.parentTask = this
      this.children.push(child)
  }

  reparent(parentTask) {
    if (this.parentTask)
      this.parentTask.children.splice(this.parentTask.children.indexOf(this), 1)
    parentTask && parentTask.adopt(this)
  }
}

parent_1 = new Task()
console.log(`parent_1 : ${parent_1 }`)
console.log(`add child 1`)
child_1 = new Task(parent_1)
console.log(`child_1: ${child_1}`)
console.log(`add child 2`)
child_2 = new Task(parent_1)
console.log(`child_1: ${child_1}`)
console.log(`child_2 : ${child_2 }`)
console.log(`add child 3`)
child_3 = new Task(parent_1)
console.log(`child_3 : ${child_3 }`)
console.log(`renumber parent 1`)
parent_1.level++
console.log(`child_1: ${child_1}`)
console.log(`child_2 : ${child_2 }`)
console.log(`child_3 : ${child_3 }`)
console.log(`add parent 2`)
parent_2 = new Task(null, 5) // new top level starting at 5
console.log(`move child 2 to parent 2`)
child_2.reparent(parent_2)
console.log(`child_1: ${child_1}`)
console.log(`child_2 : ${child_2 }`)
console.log(`child_3 : ${child_3 }`)
console.log(`move child 1 to parent 2 (might need more code to insert at correct position`)
child_1.reparent(parent_2)
console.log(`child_1: ${child_1}`)
console.log(`child_2 : ${child_2 }`)
console.log(`child_3 : ${child_3 }`)
```

Edit: allowed for moving tasks around